# If my own question is closed as a dup, I cannot see the link to the dup

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, post-notice

I accepted a suggested dup for my own question, and now I see:

[image]

But where is the duplicate? As an experienced user, I know to scroll down to the `Linked` section in the right-hand column, but to the newbie with their post closed they may be unable to find this. This box should have a link to the dup(s).

Comment: This is a bug, and it's not limited to your own questions. It affects everyone. I do not know why, or under which circumstances this bug is seen.

Comment: But the banner here links to the duplicate - now I'm confused!

Comment: @KenY-N doesn't happen on every question. Just on relatively few. But if you want a meta example (heh) [look at this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345907/newest-exact-duplicate-isnt-showing-the-duplicate-target-in-the-close-notice). It's a post on Meta.SE about this same issue and it's marked as a duplicate...but the duplicate doesn't show.

Comment: @KenY-N welp, the link I posted before is actually different to what I had in mind. [This is the question I was thinking of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345818/why-does-this-recent-meta-question-lack-a-duplicate-target) I saw it yesterday. I just now noticed that the one I found for my previous comment is different.

Comment: If you need more cases [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1538154/unable-to-extend-a-disk-space-on-windows-server) is one such case.